# Âncora suave dentro de uma DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho uma página OnePage, com o menu fixo no topo. Já consegui fazer com que os links do menu, ao serem clicados, rolem suavemente pela página. Minha dificuldade é fazer a mesma coisa dentro de uma DIV que possui OVERFLOW: HIDDEN. Trata-se de um menu de cardápio em que, ao clicar em "PIZZA DOCE" (por exemplo) é direcionado para o link, aparecendo dentro da DIV. Para ficar mais claro, desejo fazer igual ao que está no site do GLOBO ESPORTE (neste link http://globoesporte.globo.com/futebol/times/corinthians/), na área "ELENCO". Segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Poderiam me ajudar por favor? Obrigado.

Comment: Quer que a página role suavemente para um uma "ancora"?

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo de rolagem suave com jQuery. Pelo que pude entender é disso que você precisa. Vai ser necessário adaptar este exemplo no seu código, já que você não forneceu ele.

```js
$(".suave").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.conteudo{
  background:#ff7777;
  }

.ancora{
 background:#77ff77; 
 }
```

```html
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 


<a href="#ancora">Rolagem normal</a><br>
<a href="#ancora" class="suave" >Rolagem suave</a>


<div class="conteudo">
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  [Conteúdo]<br/>
  </div>

  <div id="ancora" class="ancora">Rolar até aqui</div>
```